# Accessing DOM element created using jquery .load()

Tags: php, jquery

My goal is to obtain an array of data from a mysql database using PHP for use in a javascript function; graph() in the example below.

I have chosen to do this by loading the data i need to a DOM element. I am now trying to access it. The query works and I can see the information I need in my #loadTarget div. I am having trouble accessing the innerHTML though.

According to Jquery documentation, i can use a complete function which will execute once the load is done:
.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )
Why then, when I can see the database data I need rendered in my element, can i not access it using getElementByID and innerHTML?

var dataLocation = document.getElementById("arrayTargetOne");
    var data = dataLocation.innerHTML;

The above returns data is null. If i do the same getElementById on the parent element (not the one created in my PHP .load file, the one already there), i can see the data I need. It is like the .load function is not complete. Am i missing something minor or should i take a different approach?

The Javascript/Jquery

```
$( ".selectUser" ).click(function() {

var userChoice = document.getElementById(this.id);
var user = x.innerHTML;

$("#loadTarget").load("example.php",{"data":user},function() {
var dataLocation = document.getElementById("arrayTargetOne");
var data = dataLocation.innerHTML;
alert(data);
graph();

});
```

The PHP

```
<?php
$login_errors = array();
require ("config.php");
require (MYSQL);

$arrayOne = array();
$arrayTwo = array();
$exampleQuery = $dbc->prepare("SELECT exampleFieldOne,exampleFieldTwo FROM exampleTable WHERE userID=? AND name=?");

$exampleQuery->bind_param('ss',$_SESSION['user_id'],$_POST['data']);
$exampleQuery->execute();
$exampleQuery->bind_result($a,$b);

while($exampleQuery->fetch()){

array_push($arrayOne,$a);
array_push($arrayTwo,$b);

}

echo '<span id="arrayTargetOne">';
echo json_encode($arrayOne);
echo '</span><span id="arrayTargetTwo">';
echo json_encode($arrayTwo);
echo '</span>';
?>

});
```

Comment: If you want data from an ajax call, you really ought to just use `$.get()` to fetch the data into javascript, not to put it in your DOM first.

Comment: Thanks. If I amend my request to look like the below, what does the PHP need to look like in order to pass back the data? Assuming echoing the json array won't do it?$.get("example.php",{"data":user}, function(data){
  alert("Data: " + data);
});

Comment: You should just return JSON from the PHP and let jQuery parse it for you into a javascript object as your ajax result.  Then, you'll have all the data already parsed for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = document.getElementById('loadTarget').children;
for (var i=0, len = list.length; i<len; ++i) {
    var data = list[i].nodeValue; //for text nodes, use innerHTML for elements
    //do stuff with data
}
```

The list will be a list of the created DOM nodes.